MongoDB C# Query to filter fields omitting non-digits while filtering
I have documents in MongoDB with 'SSN' string field. It could contain only digits or digits with hyphens, for ex.:

"123456789"
"12-345-6789"
"123-456789"

The incoming filter parameter could come only as digits, for ex. "123456789", "187641287" and so on.
How to build filter query to find those records? I mean the non-digits characters in 'SSN' should be ignored and only digits should be compared with filter parameter.
I looked at Builders.Filter.Where but it looks like it will not work because it accepts Expression:
ssn ('123454784') // filter ssn value coming outside

Func<MyDocument, bool> ssnExpression() => doc =>
{
    var ssnOnlyDigits = doc.SSN ?? null;
    ssnOnlyDigits = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ssnOnlyDigits) ? null : Regex.Replace(ssnOnlyDigits, @"\D", string.Empty);
    return ssnOnlyDigits != null && ssnOnlyDigits.Equals(ssn);
};

return Builders<MyDocument>.Filter.Where(ssnExpression());

Any advice will be appreciated.
P.S. I cannot store 'SSN' with only digits into DB.

hmm are you not passing in the ssn

This is 'ssn' parameter coming from outside, I updated the question.

Not sure how you create regexes in c# but take your digits-only-ssn and put -? between every digit. That -? means "one optional hyphen". So 123456789 becomes 1-?2-?3-?4-?5-?6-?7-?8-?9. Then do a regex search with that regexified ssn: find({ ssn: { $regex: "1-?2-?3-?4-?5-?6-?7-?8-?9" } }) https://mongoplayground.net/p/UHGxkuXj-mH And if you expect more than one hyphen then use -* which is "zero or more hyphens": 1-*2-*3-*4-*5-*6-*7-*8-*9

Mongo has its own regex feature which may be what you need.

To clarify my previous comment, use standard string manipulation to convert ssnOnlyDigits to the hyphenated form. Then use it in a a $regex operation or use your language's MongoDB API's automatic handling of regexes. So in python, I would do ssnOnlyDigits = 123456789; hyphenated = "-?".join(list(str(ssnOnlyDigits))). And then either: A. collection.find({"ssn": {"$regex": hyphenated}}) or B. collection.find({"ssn": re.compile(hyphenated)})

As @aneroid suggested this could be done with Regex. In C#, the code looks like the following:
ssnValue // ssn filter value coming from outside
var regex = new BsonRegularExpression("^" + string.Join("-?", ssnValue.ToCharArray()) + "$");
var filter = Builders<MyDocument>.Filter.Regex(selector, regex);

